# ERC20 token fatcory issue

Tags: factory

I have a issue with my token factory.
I defined a custom Token :

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "../interfaces/IOffer.sol";
contract CTToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, AccessControlEnumerable {
bytes32 public constant CTTOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE = keccak256("CTTOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE");

/// @notice Address of the SPcollection of this Token
address public SPcollection;
/// @notice Index of the asset inside the collection
uint256 public SPcollectionId;

address public AssociatedOffer;
uint256 public StartClaimingDate;


uint256 public cap;
bool private _mintOnceOnly=false; // variable use to mint at creationonly


constructor( string memory name, string memory symbol,uint256 cap_, address _AssociatedOffer, uint256 _StartClaimingDate, address _manager) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    _setupRole(CTTOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE, msg.sender);
     _setupRole(CTTOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE, _manager);
    cap=cap_;
    AssociatedOffer= _AssociatedOffer;
    StartClaimingDate=_StartClaimingDate;
  
}



/**
 * @dev Returns the cap on the token's total supply.
 */
function _mint(address account) public {
    require( !_mintOnceOnly ,"CT-MINT1");
   
    super._mint(account, cap);
     _mintOnceOnly=true;
}
```

}

I can create my token using :

```
      const CTTokenContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('CTToken');
      const _CTTokenContract = await CTTokenContract.deploy("TEST token",  "AM2",_offersize,_claimsContractAddress,  dateInAyear_sm, TokenCreatorAddress);
      await _CTTokenContract.deployed();
```

However if I encapsulate that in a factory using :

```
        // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8;
    
    
    import "../ContractClass/CTToken.sol";
    import "../interfaces/IOffer.sol";
    
    
    
    /// @title CTToken factory 
    /// @notice Contract factory for offers
    /// @dev Thisncontract should be deployed after the
    /// Deploying this contract as external reference removes all the unnecessary bytecode of Tokenized Assets from the Asset CTTokenings

contract CTTokenFactory {
     CTToken[] public cttokens;
    uint8 public nbCTToken=0;


    function createCTToken(string memory name, string memory symbol,uint256 cap_, address _AssociatedOffer, uint256 _StartClaimingDate) public {
        CTToken  _ct =new CTToken(name,symbol,cap_, _AssociatedOffer,_StartClaimingDate, msg.sender );
          cttokens.push(_ct); 
          nbCTToken++;

    
    }


}
```

It never works.
The transaction is in error with no understandable error.

I never get the token created....

what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Bruno

Comment: Maybe there's some error when you have _manager == msg.sender?
Also, maybe you can add some events, so that you can check the transaction receipt.
From what you share nothing becomes apparent... maybe sharing some logs and error details can help?